# Format and content of lines in pg_hba.conf file

Tags: postgresql, pg-hba.conf

I installed Postgres 9.3 yesterday on Ubuntu 18.04 (using the Ubuntu package index).  I need to add lines to the `pg_hba.conf` file to allow pgAdmin access on port 5432.

For example, I need to add a line in this format:

```
hostssl  database  user  address  auth-method  [auth-options]
```

My first question is what should I use for the the IP address in the "address" field.  I am using pgAdmin on my local computer (Windows) to access my Ubuntu 18.04 server in the cloud, but I don't have a static IP address, so entering my IP address won't do.  What IP address should I put in the address field for outside access from my local computer?  It's not clear from the docs at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/auth-pg-hba-conf.html.

My second question is how do I indicate port 5432 in the line above?  I believe that's the default listener port for Postgres, so doesn't it need to be specified in the line above?

Comment: 9.3 isn't supported anymore. It may be better to upgrade right away.

Comment: I just noticed that.  The package index contains that one now.  I'll upgrade, but I'll still have the same question.

Comment: If you want to allow all IP addresses you can use `0.0.0.0/0` (See ["Example 20.1."](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/auth-pg-hba-conf.html#EXAMPLE-PG-HBA.CONF). The port doesn't matter here.

Comment: Well, that should do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to specify in `pg_hba.conf` is not an IP address, but a *netmask*: an IP address followed by a number between 0 and 32 that tells how many bits of the address are significant.

For example

```
12.23.34.99/24
```

matches all IP addresses between `12.23.34.0` and `12.23.34.255`.

Find out in which range your possible IP addresses are and use that.

`pg_hba.conf` determines which authentication method is used for an incoming connection. It comes into play *after* the TCP connection to server port 5432 has been established.

To configure on which TCP port PostgreSQL should listen, edit `postgresql.conf` and restart PostgreSQL.